# angular $compile a dive ith ng-repeat inside

Tags: angularjs, compilation, html-table

I have the following problem:

I have some tables which would be automatically generated with angular and ng-repeat:

```
<article id="search-performance-table" class="container-fluid istable">
            <div class="printOptionElements printshow newpage size100"></div>
            <!-- Start Table Simple-->
            <section class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="SmartTableController">

                        <table id="table-performance-suche" class="table table-hover" st-table="displayed" st-safe-src="tablePerformanceSearch">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="active">
                                    [... Header Elements ...]
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="element in displayed">
                                    <td>{{element.date| date}}</td>
                                    <td>{{element.requests| number:0}}</td>
                                    <td>{{element.clicks| number:0}}</td>
                                    <td>{{element.clickRate| percentage:2}}</td>
                                    <td>{{element.carts| number:0}}</td>
                                    <td>{{element.buys| number:0}}</td>
                                    <td>{{element.conversionRate| percentage:2}}</td>
                                    <td>{{element.responseTime| number:2}} ms</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot class="font-blue-grey-light" ng-model="tablePerformanceSearchTotal">
                                <tr class="active">
                                [... Footer Elements ...]
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="12" class="text-center">
                                        <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="$root.itemsByPage1_table1" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>

                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <!-- Ende Table Simple -->
        </article>
```

Now I want produce an printview on this table. For this I copy the article element, place it in an array and append it to paper there belong. For example I want the table on page3, I copy it and paste it on the element `$("#site1")`.

```
pageElements[pageNumber][elementOnPage] = "<div id='"+this.parentNode.id+"' class='thisIs100 printPaper'>"+$("#"+this.parentNode.id).html()+"</div>";

for (j=0; j < pageElements.length; j++) {
            for (i=0; i < pageElements[j].length; i++) {
                $("#site"+j).append(""+pageElements[j][i]+"");
            }
        }
```

Now i have my papers with the elements inside. The old elements are hided. But angular is not working, cause it's not in the $scope. I compile the elements into the scope.

```
$( ".printOptionElements" ).each(function( index ) {
            var parentid = this.parentNode.id;
            $compile($("#"+parentid).children().not(".printOptionElements"))($scope);
            $scope.$apply();
        });
```

And this works for simple angular-variables in the footer, but the ng-repeat don't work. I only get:

```
<tbody>
                                <!-- ngRepeat: element in displayed -->
                            </tbody>
```

Is there a way to fix this? I try to work with `$scope.$digest()` or `$apply()` after I compiled the elements. but it doesn't work.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must to replace $ with JQuery when you are using JQuery with Angular try :

```
pageElements[pageNumber][elementOnPage] = "<div id='"+this.parentNode.id+"' class='thisIs100 printPaper'>"+jQuery("#"+this.parentNode.id).html()+"</div>";

for (j=0; j < pageElements.length; j++) {
            for (i=0; i < pageElements[j].length; i++) {
                jQuery("#site"+j).append(""+pageElements[j][i]+"");
            }
        }
```

And :

```
jQuery( ".printOptionElements" ).each(function( index ) {
            var parentid = this.parentNode.id;
            $compile(jQuery("#"+parentid).children().not(".printOptionElements"))($scope);
           if(!$scope.$$phase){
                 $scope.$apply();
           }
        });
```

Try it first and let me know if it's better ? :)

What can you see in console ? 
The part with $scope variable is in controller ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.  I replaced every $ with jQuery. But nothing happens. But the other jqueryelements in angular also worked with $, so i don't think that is the problem. But thanks for your help

Comment: You have placed $scope.$apply() in $$phase test ?

Comment: Yeah "jQuery( ".printOptionElements" ).each(function( index ) {
                var parentid = this.parentNode.id;
                $compile(jQuery("#"+parentid).children().not(".printOptionElements"))($scope);
                if(!$scope.$$phase){
                 $scope.$apply();
                }
            });"

Comment: Do you have lignes in your console ? you can use an useful plugin able on chrome ,"ng-inspector" watch it ;) 
[link] https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj

Comment: i have one error message on the console, but i dont understand it, and it doenst affect the the output (until now?). TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined
    at compositeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.17/angular.js:7152:36)
    [...] at compositeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.17/angular.js:7149:13)<div id="contentarea" ng-view="" class="ng-scope">  This is the eror message. but insteat of the ng-repeat it works without problems ad compiled every angular elements to the scope.

Comment: I testet your $$phase.test.  if(!$scope.$$phase) never triggers

Comment: $$phase test  value never is true if there is already a digest phase , if you don't use this if you'll have error message like "digest already in progress" in your console, it's the better way to use $scope.$apply() to prevent errors =)

Comment: But i don't have an digest already in progrss error. hmm. :( Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can try to get out of the each the $compile instance and build an array in each who'll used to $compile instance after loop ?

Comment: I actual triy to remove all $compilers from the code and at the end of the function i insert an $compile($("body"))($scope);
                if(!$scope.$$phase){
                    $scope.$apply();
                }. But it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Ok looks like the problem is on another point. i console.logged the entry of the array on pageElements[pageNumber][elementOnPage] = "<div id='"+this.parentNode.id+"' class='thisIs100 printPaper'>"+$("#"+this.parentNode.id).html()+"</div>"; At this point there is no ng-repeat. So later the compiler has nothing to work with.

Comment: So you have a new way to fix it ? or still not ?